# Using Scala in Java - how to convert a Java Object to Option<Object>

Tags: java, scala

I'm writing in java, and I need to use external library that is written in scala. In particular, I need the following [constructor](http://apache.mirrors.tds.net/kafka/0.8.2.1/scaladoc/index.html#kafka.api.PartitionMetadata):

```
new PartitionMetadata(partitionId: Int, leader: Option[Broker], replicas: Seq[Broker], isr: Seq[Broker] = collection.this.Seq.empty[Nothing], errorCode: Short = kafka.common.ErrorMapping.NoError)
```

I was able to convert all but the `leader : Option[Broker]` and the `Seq` parameters in my java code:

```
partitionMetadata = new kafka.api.PartitionMetadata(
  partitionId, leader.getBroker(),(Seq)brokerReplicas, (Seq)brokerIsr, errorCode);
```

I'm getting the following error in my editor:

```
'PartitionMetadata(int, scala.Option<kafka.cluster.Broker>, scala.collection.Seq<kafka.cluster.Broker>, scala.collection.Seq<kafka.cluster.Broker>, short)' in 'kafka.api.PartitionMetadata'
cannot be applied to (int, kafka.cluster.Broker, scala.collection.Seq, scala.collection.Seq, short)
```

Is it possible to use a Scala constructor in Java? Also, how do I convert a Java Object (leader) to a Option?

Lastly, am I converting the ArrayList -> Scala.collection.Seq fields correctly?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it's possible to use this scala constructor in Java. The error message from your editor gives you a hint: it expects a `scala.Option<kafka.cluster.Broker>` as the second argument.

You can create that scala.Option as follows: `scala.Option.apply(leader.getBroker())`

Also, you shouldn't just cast your java array lists to scala.Seq. Instead, check out [`scala.collection.JavaConversions`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.JavaConversions$)

Comment: thanks for the answer!

From the conversion, it looks like there is no way to convert any type into scala.collection.Seq



Is there another method for conversion that I use instead? Is there a way to create an empty scala.collection.Seq in Java, then subsequently populate it with my elements?

Comment: You can use `asScalaBuffer`. Check out its method header: it takes in a `java.util.List` (which an ArrayList satisfies), and returns a `scala.collection.mutable.Buffer` (which extends Seq)